# System of 2 modular equations

Tags: proof-verification, modular-arithmetic

I don't know where I am making mistake in my calculations. Please verify:

$ x \equiv 569^{679} \mod 851 $

Note that $851 = 23.37, 679 = 12.56 + 7 = 11.61 + 8 $ and by Fermat's Little Theorem $569^{36} \equiv 1 \mod 37$ and $569^{22} \equiv 1 \mod 23$

Then we have $569^{7} \equiv 14^{7} \equiv 23 \mod 37$ and
$569^{8} \equiv 17^{8} \equiv 18 \mod 23$.

So we can solve the system with Chinese Remainder Theorem:

$a = \{18,23\}$, 
$M = \{37,23\}$, 
$\bar{M}=\{14,23\}$, 
$\bar{M'}=\{5,29\}$

The upper product is $18.37.5 = 3330$ and the lower is $23.23.29 = 15341$.
Then $ x \equiv 18671 \mod 851 = 800$

But the answer isn't $800$, I am supposed to get $97$. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Why do you compute $679$ modulo $56$ and $61$?  (or modulo $12$ and $11$ if that's what you are doing?)  $679\equiv 31 \pmod {36}$ and $569\equiv 14\pmod {37}$ so I'd have said you wanted to compute $14^{31} \pmod {37}$  Similarly, I'd have looked at $17^{19}\pmod {23}$.

Comment: No, that's not what I did. Those are the numbers from the euclidean division. $569^{679} = {569^{11}}^{61}.{569}^{8}$ and since L.T.F. this will be only ${569}^{8}$. Similar for  $12.56+7$

Comment: Still not following.  $11\times 61 = 671$ and $671\equiv 23 \pmod {36}$  (and $23+8=31$ matching the $31$ computed in my earlier comment.)

Comment: but $11.61+8=679$. 
I noted that $569^{11} \equiv 1 \mod 23$, and then, as $569^{679} = (569^{11})^{61}.569^8$, I will have $569^{679} \equiv 569^{8} \mod 23$. The remainder of $569 : 23$ is $17$, then $569^{8} \equiv 17^{8} \mod 23$, which is equivalent to $18 \mod 23$ Then the same process to the other equation, of modulo $37$

Comment: Let me try it a different way.  We easily see that $679=18*36+31$.  Then mod $37$ we can write $a^{679}\equiv a^{36*18}a^{31}\equiv \left(a^{36}\right)^{18}a^{31}\equiv 1^{18}a^{31}\equiv a^{31}\pmod {37}$.

Comment: Your work is very hard to follow.  $569^{11}$ is not $1 \pmod {23}$, it is $-1$.

Comment: You're right. That's where I was wrong. I'm gonna restart the exercise using your sugestion. Thanks.